# Associate MIME Type with Shell Script?

Tags: linux, firefox, bash, centos, mime-types

I want to associate any file type with a .abc extension with the following shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo arg 1 is: $1
```

The .abc type files just have text, but I want to ensure that opening a file with a .abc extension invokes my script (in this case just echoing back the file). It's giving me problems because my script isn't considered an application.

The ultimate goal is that I'm writing a web server that will process any request for file types with a .abc extension and invoke my shell script as a handler.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

(Using CentOS 6.5)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, your script is not considered an application because it is not an executable.

```
 chmod 755 script_name
```

should solve that.